# getting _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-relief" error in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a simple calculator but when I try to configure my entry with 'relief' method it is showing the error `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-relief"`.

I don't know why this is showing this error

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry('400x400')
win.title('Simple Calculator')
win.configure(bg='Peach puff')
value = tk.StringVar()
entry = ttk.Entry(win, font=('Helvetica', 35, 'bold'), justify='right', textvariable=value, relief=tk.SUNKEN)
entry.pack(padx=30, pady=15, side='top', fill='both')

def spin():
    pass

button_images = {'one': tk.PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\hruthik\Desktop\Pics\numbers\one.png')}
b_one = ttk.Button(win, image=button_images['one'], command=spin, borderwidth=0)
b_one.pack(pady=20)
win.resizable(False, False)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: You just have to read the available documentation for the ttk Button widget to see that the error is telling the truth.

Answer (score 2):

The `ttk` package widgets have different options than the standard `tkinter` widgets. For example, the `ttk.Entry` widget has no option for relief, and the `ttk.Button` widget has no option for borderwidth. Try using the `tk.Entry` and `tk.Button` widgets instead, if you want to specify these options

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry('400x400')
win.title('Simple Calculator')
win.configure(bg='Peach puff')
value = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(win, font=('Helvetica', 35, 'bold'), justify='right', textvariable=value, relief=tk.SUNKEN)
entry.pack(padx=30, pady=15, side='top', fill='both')


def spin():
    pass


button_images = {'one': tk.PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\hruthik\Desktop\Pics\numbers\one.png')}
b_one = tk.Button(win, image=button_images['one'], command=spin, borderwidth=0)
b_one.pack(pady=20)
win.resizable(False, False)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I was so baffled why none of the config options like insertwidth existed for my Entry widget.